How to get the values from key/value pairs declared in an object as Azure pipeline parameters
I have an object parameter declared in a pipeline. I'm just wondering how I can access the values of what here would be info1, info2 & info3
parameters:
 - name: info
   displayName: Information
   type: object
   default:
     info1: testinfo1
     info2: testinfo2
     info3: testinfo3

I tried calling it in my script as follows but it's not returning anything. I tried running an echo to see what value I'm getting but it's just empty
az keyvault secret set --vault-name ${{ parameters.info.info1 }} 

I also tried assigning a variable the value but it's also not working
I tried searching online, checking the documentation from Microsoft for parameters and I tried searching Gemini but the suggestions didn't work either

Are you passing the Info object to the template? Perhaps you can show that too.

Hi Eliew, can you share a Minimal, Reproducible Example to reproduce the issue?

Hey guys, apologies for the late response. @burntsugar I haven't passed the value to a template.
@MiaoTian-MSFT This was my last attempt on Friday
`- job:
displayName: 'test'
steps:

${{ each schema in parameters.info }} :

powershell: |
Write-Host "Info name is '${{ info.key }}' and value is '${{ info.value}}' "`
Sorry I'm not able to get the code on it's own lines..




@eliew please edit your question and include the job code there.

Hi, thanks for sharing the Job code.  I noticed that you have confirmed it is working after you created a new pipeline. And your new question has been answered too, please check the answers.

You can either use your parameters statically or dynamically, depending on your use case.
Example 1 - accessing parameter values statically
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
 - name: info
   displayName: Information
   type: object
   default:
     info1: testinfo1
     info2: testinfo2
     info3: testinfo3

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: |
      echo "Info1: ${{ parameters.info.info1 }}"
      echo "Info2: ${{ parameters.info.info2 }}"
      echo "Info3: ${{ parameters.info.info3 }}"
    displayName: Show parameter values

Running the pipeline:

Example 2 - accessing parameter values dynamically
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
 - name: info
   displayName: Information
   type: object
   default:
     info1: testinfo1
     info2: testinfo2
     info3: testinfo3

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each info in parameters.info }}:
      - script: |
          echo "${{ info.key }}: ${{ info.value }}"
        displayName: Show ${{ info.key }} value

Running the pipeline:

EDIT 1
Regarding your job:
- job:   
  displayName: 'test'
  steps:
    - ${{ each schema in parameters.info }} :
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Info name is '${{ info.key }}' and value is '${{ info.value }}' "

This doesn't work because you're declaring a variable named schema, but in the script body you're using info.
Fix:
- job:   
  displayName: 'test'
  steps:
    - ${{ each schema in parameters.info }} :
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Info name is '${{ schema.key }}' and value is '${{ schema.value }}' "


Regarding the "Edit1", I fixed it the "schema.key" and "schema.value" but it still returns
"Schema name is ' ' and value is ' ' ". Sorry I tried sending a screenshot of the error but I'm not able to for some reason

@eliew impossible to tell where the problem is without seeing code. Is the job in a separate template? Did you define the parameters for that template? ... Please edit your question and add all the required code that allow us to reproduce the issue.

@eliew you should edit your question instead of posting the code in the comments. As per the other problem, you should post a new question.

It's working now. I created the pipeline from scratch and I'm getting the values to display properly. Is it possible to add that loop in an azurecli task inlinescript? Or should I create a new ticket for that question?

@eliew it's probably better to post a new question.
